# Bootstrap horizontal form has additional margins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The button that's next to a column containing a `select` element appears to have some extra margins on it. On my actual site it seems to be extra positive margin, while on CodePen it appears to be negative.

[image]

I suspect they are the same problem though with the markup though. Here's the CodePen demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gabZMo?editors=100

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-horizontal col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-control">...</select>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-default col-sm-4">New Event</button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Free Quote</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've looked through the Bootstrap docs and this *should* be the correct markup. I've also tried wrapping the `button` in its own column, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `col-sm-4` directly on the button. Put `btn-block` on the button and stick it in a `col-sm-4` div, like so:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-horizontal col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="1">Test Event</option>
          <option value="7">Test Event 2: The Re-testening</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">New Event</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Free Quote</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options to resolve the problem,

Put the `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Free Quote</button>` inside `<div class="form-group"></div>`

Reason the button is pushing left of right because `col-sm-4` selector has left and right padding `15px` which is getting overwritten by `btn-default` selector `padding: 6px 12px;`

So add custom selector `custom-margin` and define custom CSS

1 HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control">...</select>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default col-sm-4 custom-margin">New Event</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Free Quote</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/s63akpks/2/)

2 HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control">...</select>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default col-sm-4 custom-margin">New Event</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Free Quote</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/s63akpks/3/)

Or Do it right way

3 HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control">...</select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">New Event</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Free Quote</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

[Fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/s63akpks/5/)